# c++/cli перегрузка оператора присваивания для ref class

Tags: c++-cli

При перегрузке оператора присваивания выдает ошибку:

> error C2440: return: невозможно преобразовать "FlyLevel" в "FlyLevel ^"

```
ref class FlyLevel
{
private:
    String ^mIdCfl; 
    double mMeters; 
    double mFoot;   
public:
    FlyLevel();
    FlyLevel (String ^idCfl, double meters, double foot);
    String ^get_IdCfl();   
    double Meters();    
    double Foot();       
    FlyLevel ^operator = (const FlyLevel ^rhs);
    {
        mIdCfl = rhs->mIdCfl;
        mMeters = rhs->mMeters;
        mFoot = rhs->mFoot;
        return  *this;
    }
 };
```

Как правильно перегрузить оператор присваивания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два решения:

```
FlyLevel ^operator = (const FlyLevel ^rhs);
{
    mIdCfl = rhs->mIdCfl;
    mMeters = rhs->mMeters;
    mFoot = rhs->mFoot;
    return this;
}
```

```
void operator = (const FlyLevel ^rhs);
{
    mIdCfl = rhs->mIdCfl;
    mMeters = rhs->mMeters;
    mFoot = rhs->mFoot;
}
```

Интересно, что в обоих случаях следующий код компилируется:

```
FlyLevel ^a = gcnew FlyLevel("", 0, 0), ^b = gcnew FlyLevel("", 0, 0), ^c;
c = a = b;
```

Что, впрочем, менее странно, чем кажется, поскольку ни один из вариантов оператора при этом присваивании не вызывается.

Comment: Возможно, инициализация не считается присваиванием, как и в обыкновенном C++.

Comment: @VladD, вероятно фишка в том, что мы присваиваем указатель, а оператор перегружен для класса? При чём тут инициализация, я не понял. `c=a=b` - это не инициализация.

Comment: И правда, `c = a = b` — не инициализация. Тогда я и не знаю, что думать.

Comment: @VladD, но ведь присваивается указатель. Неразыменованный. Надо как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Помимо предложных выше решений, такой вариант тоже сработал:

```
FlyLevel %operator = (const FlyLevel %rhs)  
{
    mIdCfl = rhs.mIdCfl;
    mMeters = rhs.mMeters;
    mFoot = rhs.mFoot;
    return  *this;
}
```